# Swift 4 Timer.invalidate() returns "Expression resolves to an unused function" error

Tags: ios, swift, timer

I am making a game that has a timer displaying how long the current session has elapsed. I've followed a couple tutorials and read the documentation and can't seem to figure out why this is returning an error. Here is my code:

```
var timerT = Timer()

func startTimer () {
    self.timerT = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(timeFunc), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

@objc func timeFunc (_ timer: Timer) {
    timeS += 1
}
@IBAction func newGameAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    Timer.invalidate(timerT)
    game = SetGame()
    updateUIfromModel()
    startTimer()

}
```

Much Mahalo.

Comment: You mean `self,timerT.invalidate()`, you are trying to invoke invalidate on the class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to call `invalidate()` on an instance of a `Timer`, not on `Timer` itself.

Change:

```
Timer.invalidate(timerT)
```

to:

```
timerT.invalidate()
```

Comment: The reason this returned an error message about an *unused function* is that calling an instance method on the class and passing an instance to it actually returns that function.  So `Timer.invalidate(timerT)` is equal to `timerT.invalidate`, so you've created the function but didn't call it.  `Timer.invalidate(timerT)()` would have invalidated the timer as well, but of course `timerT.invalidate()` is the right way to call it.